# Logic behind nth day before a given day

Tags: c++, math, logic

**Given:**

0. Sunday
1. Monday
2. Tuesday
3. Wednesday
4. Thursday
5. Friday
6. Saturday

suppose the day is 2 (Tuesday) and n days is 10, then we have you count 10 days before Tuesday, we get 6 (Saturday).

*Code:*

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int day, n;
    cin >> day >> n; 
    int x = n % 7;
    int ans = day - x;
    if(ans > 0) {
        cout << ans;
    }
    else {
        cout << ans + 7;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone please explain the logic of the program? For example, I understood why use `n % 7`(*because we wish to get the range between 0-6*). I did not understand why we use `day - x` and `ans + 7`.

Comment: what is the task that this code is supposed to solve?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number it gives  the value of the nth day which is before a given day. if day is sunday and n is 3. it goes 3 days before sunday and returns that day(thursday)

Comment: *i did not understand why we use day-x and ans+7* -- Forget about the program for a moment -- how would you solve this problem on paper, and does your paper solution differ from what the program is doing?  For example, think of placing the days in a circle, similar to a 7-hour clock.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Indeed i have solved it on a paper. i understood,but i am unable to come up with a solution of my own. i don't understand why we subtract day-x

Comment: *i don't understand why we subtract day-x* --Well, the program is only a few lines long, and you could easily run this by hand.  Did you try different inputs with the program to see why the subtraction is done?  And note, the subtraction is accompanied by a test for a negative value.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes i have tried it with different inputs. it works fine.

Comment: *i did not understand why we use day-x* -- I am not sure what your question really is then.  You see that the subtraction is required for the program to work correctly, otherwise the answer is not correct.  If you say you went through this by hand, what would happen if you *didn't* subtract or add?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie gotcha, but i want to know the logic behind it. why do we subtract the current day with the reminder of the nth day?

Comment: Ever did clock arithmetic?  You would do the same thing if you were given a problem stating "It is 3:00.  What is the time 10 hours before?".  The only difference is that there are 12 values instead of 7.

Comment: *"i did not understand why we use `day-x`"* -- you do not understand why you would subtract to find something that comes before something else??? How would you find the number that is `3` numbers before `8`? *(OK, there are three parts to that expression, `day`, `-`, and `x`. However, you did not say which parts you do not understand, so I am free to assume that none were understood. Did you want to be more precise in your question?)*

Comment: *"i did not understand why we use [...] `ans+7`"* -- try an experiment. Output `ans` instead of `ans+7` and use inputs that cause that line to be executed. What happened to your output? Why is adding seven needed?

Answer (score 1):

Simply, you need to return `x` days before the current `day`, that's why you subtracted `x` from `day`. For the other part, after subtraction, you may get a negative value, so you must add `7` to it to keep it with the range of 0 to 6, and it is worthy to mention that the correct condition is `if(ans >= 0)`.